# Having multiple suppression lists in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio, suppressionlist

At the moment we are using MC suppression lists to avoid emails being sent to a blacklist we have. The issue is that **we would now like to have three different lists of emails to whom we should never send an email**.

I guess suppression lists is not the way to go because in a `Send Email` event only one can be referenced, but I do not know for certain. Here below is where we reference it (*in the Email Send configuration*):

[image: Suppression list reference]

I would like to know how this use case is usually approached, or if there is any workaround for the given problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Combine the 3 suppression lists into one? or you could use an exclusion script

Comment: @Data_Kid well, the first option is kinda discarded cause it would end up being unmaintainable imo, and the second one... Unless someone else comes up with something else, might be the answer. I'm concerned with performance tho. Would it affect?

Comment: Performance wise you would take a big hit with the exclusion script as you would be querying 3 lists . You could automate the creation of the final exclusion list from option 1 no?

Comment: are you suppressing the list from every single send email send (including triggered) form that BU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get 'Auto Suppression Lists' enabled on your account on the Parent Business Unit.

Create an Auto Suppression list from Admin > Auto Suppression Lists. An ASL can be applied to various business units and/or send classifications. You can also create multiple ASL's

Add the your suppression records a data extension.

Include in your automation a file extract to extract the records from your DE to CSV and upload to Safehouse

Also include a step in your automation to then import from Safehouse the CSV file and Import into the Auto Suppression List.

The auto Suppression list works at Email Address level (not subscriber key) and is applied on every send (based in send classifications and business units).

If a contact appears in a data extension or list and has been added to the auto Suppression list then they will be automatically suppressed. You therefore don't need to manually add the suppression list to each send

Comment: Can I have multiple auto-suppression lists, one for each purpose?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple auto-suppression lists. They will automatically apply at send time .... I found you this guide (with screenshots) which might be of some use : https://dare2mull.wordpress.com/2017/06/13/salesforce-marketing-cloud-exacttarget-auto-suppression-of-contacts/

Answer (score 0):

not sure how unique the emails are, but if they are at the domain level you could use list detective.  user-initiated sends seem to have more flexibility in terms of including/excluding different data extensions and suppression lists.